# How Do I Copy Comments When Generating an Interface From a Class In Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, macros, comments

In Visual Studio I can use the **Refactor -> Extract Interface...** option to generate an interface from public methods on a class. However this does not copy across the XML comments and I end up spending several minutes copying and pasting them. Are there any macros or add-ins that can use the existing comments on the class when auto creating an interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)?

When I extracted an interface using ReSharper, the XML comments on the extracted methods were preserved.

Comment: OK I will try Resharper then. The only thing that has put me off it so far is the price but I guess that it could be worth it for all the time it saves. In the mean time **if anyone else can find a cheaper alternative then please say so!**

Comment: I know what you mean about the cost, but honestly I have found that it was completely worth it for the amount of time it has saved me.

Answer (score 3):

The [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) addin will probably help you out here.

Comment: I played around with GhostDoc a bit but I'm not sure it can do what I want unless I make some serious changes to the built in templates. It would probably work better if I was trying to add comments to the class based on comments on the interface (i.e. the reverse of what I need).